# handling onClick with React styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a problem where I'm trying to create a memory game grid and when I click on a grid item it opens up.
Currently I have a working grid but I've only managed to work it with hover, and don't understand how to make it work with click event when the state changes.

Basically my grid item code tree is

```
<Box onClick={this.handleOpenCard}>
  <Front />
  <Back>
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </Back>
</Box>
```

What I want to do is when I click on card I change component state `open` to `true`. And when this state is true I want with styled-components perform the css animation which rotates card to 180deg.
Please see full component code where currently works when I hover on item, please give me ideas how to achieve that or maybe refactor code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Box = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;
`;

const Front = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 1s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;

    ${Box}:hover & {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 75px;
    }
`;
const Back = Front.extend`
    background-color: #ffeb3b;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

    ${Box}:hover & {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
`;

class Card extends Component {
    state = {
        open: false
    };

    handleOpenCard = e => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Box open={this.state.open} onClick={this.handleOpenCard}>
                <Front />
                <Back>
                    <img
                        src={
                            process.env.PUBLIC_URL +
                            `/images/svg/${this.props.path}`
                        }
                    />
                </Back>
            </Box>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access props in styled-components very easily.

In your Box: `transform: ${props => props.open ? rotateY(180deg) : rotateY(0deg)}`

To pass props to children:

```
Front = styled.div`

`

Box = styled.div`
   ${Front} {
      transform: ${props => props.open ? rotateY(180deg) : rotateY(0deg)}
    }
`
```

Comment: Problem is that I need to perform an transform on `Front` and `Back` components when I have clicked on `Box`. This animation doesn't work on `Box` component.

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: Nope this doesn't work too. Only way how I managed to work it is passing `open` props to `Front` and `Back` components and then in `Front` styled-component calling `${Box} & {
  transform: ${props =>
   props.open ? "rotateY(180deg)" : "rotateY(0deg)"};
 }` but I don't think it's the most appropriate way to pass for both components the same prop.